# spring boot gradle app on ubuntu: unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have an existing Spring app that I want to convert to a Spring Boot app. So I have added th Application.java file in my java source directory and execute my gradlwe script as usual. However, when I run the build command, a get an error saying 'unable to access jarfile' - although I specify the jarfile name in my build script and on my command line. Below is the build.gradle file and the output. What is wrong here?

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}   

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

archivesBaseName = 'spring4'
version = '1' 

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.3.3.RELEASE'    
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3"
    compile "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.13"

    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    } 
jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources"
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/Spring4RESTAngularJS$ ./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:war
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.772 secs
Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/Spring4RESTAngularJS$
```

check target directory:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/Spring4RESTAngularJS$ ll build/libs/
total 53697
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant        0 Sep 15 11:25 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant     4096 Sep 13 09:54 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 30698749 Sep 15 11:25 spring4-1.war*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 24281990 Sep 15 11:24 spring4-1.war.original*
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/Spring4RESTAngularJS$
```